# Spring & Hibernate don't save my records in database

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, save

I've read many topics with the same problem like my but it didn't solved so I've decided write here.

The problem is that when I want to edit or delete record in my project, every function implemented in Java seems to run correctly, but there aren't any changes in database. 
For example in my project I've got model called 'Oddzial' (in english it's department).
I can add new Oddzial (Department) to the database and I'll see the changes. But if I want to delete everything, there aren't any errors but also there aren't any changes in database. The record which should be deleted is still in database.

Here are my files:

**Model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="oddzial")
public class Oddzial implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer oddzial_id;

@Size(min=3, max=25, message="test message.")
private String miasto;

@Size(min=5, max=50, message="test message.")
private String ulica;

public Integer getOddzial_id() {
    return oddzial_id;
}

public void setOddzial_id(Integer oddzial_id) {
    this.oddzial_id = oddzial_id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return oddzial_id;
}

public void setId(Integer id_oddzial) {
    this.oddzial_id = id_oddzial;
}

public String getMiasto() {
    return miasto;
}

public void setMiasto(String miasto) {
    this.miasto = miasto;
}

public String getUlica() {
    return ulica;
}

public void setUlica(String ulica) {
    this.ulica = ulica;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" + oddzial_id + "] " + ulica + " " + miasto;
}
}
```

**Here is Oddzial's DAO:**

```
@Repository
public class OddzialDAOImpl implements OddzialDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public void addOddzial(Oddzial oddzial) {
    getCurrentSession().save(oddzial);
}

public void updateOddzial(Oddzial oddzial) {
    Oddzial oddzialToUpdate = getOddzial(oddzial.getId());
    oddzialToUpdate.setMiasto(oddzial.getMiasto());
    oddzialToUpdate.setUlica(oddzial.getUlica());
    getCurrentSession().update(oddzialToUpdate);
}

public Oddzial getOddzial(int id) {
    Oddzial oddzial = (Oddzial) getCurrentSession().get(Oddzial.class, id);
    return oddzial;
}

public void deleteOddzial(int id) {
    Oddzial oddzial = getOddzial(id);
    if (oddzial != null)
        getCurrentSession().delete(oddzial);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Oddzial> getOddzialy() {
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Oddzial").list();
}
}
```

**Here is OddzialService:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class OddzialServiceImpl implements OddzialService {

@Autowired
private OddzialDAO oddzialDAO;

@Override
public void addOddzial(Oddzial oddzial) {
    oddzialDAO.addOddzial(oddzial);     
}

@Override
public void updateOddzial(Oddzial oddzial) {
    oddzialDAO.updateOddzial(oddzial);
}

@Override
public Oddzial getOddzial(int id) {
    return oddzialDAO.getOddzial(id);
}

@Override
public void deleteOddzial(int id) {
    oddzialDAO.deleteOddzial(id);
}

@Override
public List<Oddzial> getOddzialy() {
    return oddzialDAO.getOddzialy();
}

}
```

**And here is Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/oddzial")
public class OddzialController {

@Autowired
private OddzialService oddzialService;

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addOddzialPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add-oddzial-form");
    modelAndView.addObject("oddzial", new Oddzial());
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addingOddzial(@ModelAttribute @Valid Oddzial oddzial, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "add-oddzial-form";
    }
    oddzialService.addOddzial(oddzial);
    String message = "OddziaĹ‚ zostaĹ‚ pomyĹ›lnie dodany do bazy.";

    return "list-of-oddzials";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/list")
public ModelAndView listOfOddzials() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("list-of-oddzials");

    List<Oddzial> oddzials = oddzialService.getOddzialy();
    modelAndView.addObject("oddzials", oddzials);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editOddzialPage(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("edit-oddzial-form");
    Oddzial oddzial = oddzialService.getOddzial(id);
    modelAndView.addObject("oddzial",oddzial);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView edditingOddzial(@ModelAttribute Oddzial oddzial, @PathVariable Integer id) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");

    oddzialService.updateOddzial(oddzial);

    String message = "Dane zostaĹ‚y zmodyfikowane.";
    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);

    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteOddzial(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
    oddzialService.deleteOddzial(id);
    String message = "OddziaĹ‚ zostaĹ‚ usuniÄ™ty.";
    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
    return modelAndView;
}

}
```

**The content of my Spring configuration file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/tutorial" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.carrental" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="256" />
</bean>

<bean id="saltSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
    <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username" />
</bean>

<!-- <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping"> 
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"></property> </bean> <bean 
    class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter"> <property 
    name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"></property> </bean> <flow:flow-executor 
    id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry" /> <flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" 
    base-path="/WEB-INF/flows"> <flow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" 
    /> </flow:flow-registry> -->

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:component-scan
    base-package="pl.carrental" />
```

**The content of web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>localizationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>localizationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: So you can add records but you can't modify or delete them? I notice that you have `show_sql` set to `true` in the Hibernate properties. Can you see what SQL Hibernate is generating when you try to delete/modify a record?

Comment: does an object with that id exist on the database, if you set a breakpoint on getCurrentSession().delete() does it get hit?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. The line:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

must be in servlet-context.xml. Not in root-config.xml like in my case. Now transactions are committed and I can delete and update records.